# Advice about database design with tokens

Tags: regex, database-design, compiler-construction, tokenize

If i going to create a app for alerts, so users can post little messages about traffic, crimes, and other news, how difficult and/or good could it be if i would implement a sort of compiler that analyze each piece of the msg, and then categorize it in sections like crime/murder or traffic/reallySlow.

I think that a easier approach like obligate the user to select the appropriate category would be more appropriate:

```
create table alert{
   id_alert int not null primary key auto_increment,
   alert varchar(255),
   id_sub_category,
   foreign key(id_sub_category) references sub_category(id_sub_category)
}

create table sub_category{
   id_sub_category int not null primary key auto_increment,
   sub_category varchar(45), 
   id_category,
   foreign key(id_category) references category(id_category)
}

create table category{
   id_category int not null primary key auto_increment,
   category  varchar(45),   
}
```

I need advice about how difficult could be to implement the first approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database design seems appropriate enough, not knowing much about the final solution needed.

Your ultimate question really has nothing to do with database design however.  You seem to need to create some kind of algorithm that would interpret the raw user input about an event and automatically classify it according to some kind of keywords.  This is not a trivial exercise and would be error prone.

You are correct that the easier, and probably more accurate, approach would be to have the user self select the categories.  This would probably be the best user experience as well since because you would be expecting certain type of reports anyways, the user could get to the right classification with a few presses instead of typing out descriptions.